# Can you prove a set is not open if its complement is open?

Tags: general-topology

Can we prove the set of natural numbers as a subset of the reals is not open by saying that its complement is a union of open intervals so its open which means the natural numbers are not open?

I know the straightforward proof is just to take open balls of distance 1/2, but I was wondering if we can prove this by taking complements.

Comment: Not without using properties specific to the real numbers: there are spaces in which many open sets have open complements.

Comment: I had thought that openness/closedness wasn't mutually exclusive. I've never had a topology course though, and am just self-studying, so I'm not sure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set

Comment: for example, in a topological space $X$, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open, and so are their complements

Comment: There's no reason the complement of an open set isn't open.  Is there?  After all, a set could be both open and closed.  Then its compliment is both open and closed.  There's nothing intrisically wrong with that.

Comment: "I had thought that openness/closedness wasn't mutually exclusive."  They aren't.  For example Example:  $\mathbb R$ is open and $\mathbb R^c = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ is also open so $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$ are both open *and* closed.  Now it so happens in the real numbers with the Euclidean Metric topology, it does happen to be true that the only sets that are both open and closed are $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$. But that is not true of other topologies.  And if you do use this, you must *prove* it first.

Comment: Based on "Complex Function Theory" [Palka], and focusing only on $\mathbb{C}$: [1] A set is closed if and only if its complement is open [2] An open set can not contain any of its boundary pts [3] A closed set must (therefore) contain all of its boundary pts [4] Therefore, the only way that a set can be simultaneously open and closed is if there are no boundary pts associated with the set [5] Therefore, in $\mathbb{C}$, the only sets that are simultaneously open and closed are the empty set, and $\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a set and its complement are both open, then it's open and closed, or *clopen*.

A *connected* space has by definition only two clopen subsets, itself and the empty set.

So in answer to your *second* question,  yes, since the naturals are a proper subset of the reals, and the reals are connected, it suffices to prove the complement is open.

However this won't always work: a disconnected space has proper subsets which are clopen.  Thus the answer to the question in the title, which is more general, is no.